# how to reload .bashrc in dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am adding many things to the .bashrc in the Dockerfile which is necessary to execute some of the commands I want to run later in the Dockerfile,
I tried `source .bashrc` which does not work.
I tried using `RUN /bin/bash -c --login ...` but I get an error : `mesg: ttyname failed: inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: This is terribly unclear. Maybe for a start [edit] your question to show your actual `Dockerfile` and explain what you are trying to accomplish. The requirement to add things to `.bashrc` sounds extremely dubious in the first place.

Comment: I am using ROS, in order to set up the dependencies I add different paths for the dependencies to bashrc including opencv library paths.

Comment: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment suggests adding a single `source` line to your `.bashrc` and keeping the dependencies in an external file. That would make a lot more sense.

Comment: `.bashrc` is used for **interactive** shells. Docker `RUN` commands create noninteractive shells. It's not expected to use `.bashrc` at all, so the problem isn't that it needs to be reloaded -- the problem is that it's _not loaded at all in the first place_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each command in a Dockerfile creates a new temporary container, but without tty ([issue 1870](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1870), discussed in [PR 4955](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/4955), but closed in favor of [PR 4882](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/4882)).

The lack of tty during docker builds triggers the `ttyname failed: inappropriate ioctl for device` error message.

What you can try instead is running a wrapper script which in it will source the `.bashrc`.

`Dockerfile`:

```
COPY myscript /path/to/myscript
RUN /path/to/myscript
```

`myscript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/.bashrc
# rest of the commands
```

[Abderrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2992178/abderrahim) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778021/how-to-reload-bashrc-in-dockerfile/50780759?noredirect=1#comment105647676_50780759):

> In my case it was [for `nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating): it adds an `init` script to `.bashrc` therefore it wasn't usable in the Dockerfile context.
>   Ended up making an install script with it's dependent command.

Comment: While this is all correct and true, the questien looks like a massive [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I find it hard to imagine a situation where you would actually need this.

Comment: @tripleee I landed here looking for a way to load a Java $CLASSPATH variable that had to be set dynamically (i.e. a situation where neither ENV nor ARG can be used, and where writing the desired CLASSPATH value to .bashrc is one workaround)

Comment: @VonC Sorry, I didn't try it—I ended up deciding that, if I was going to be writing an extra script anyway, I could just set export the CLASSPATH temporarily in the script (without worrying about .bashrc).

Comment: In my case it was for [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating) it adds an init script to `.bashrc` therefore it wasn't usable in the Dockerfile context. Ended up making an install script with it's dependent commands

Comment: @Abderrahim Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

We can workaround that using [`$BASH_ENV`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

```bash
FROM ubuntu

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV BASH_ENV="/tmp/vars"

RUN echo "export MY_VAR=my_value" >> $BASH_ENV
RUN echo "export MY_VAR2=my_value2" >> $BASH_ENV

RUN echo "MY_VAR = $MY_VAR"
RUN echo "MY_VAR2 = $MY_VAR2"
```

```bash
#7 [4/5] RUN echo "MY_VAR = $MY_VAR"
#7 0.313 MY_VAR = my_value
#7 DONE 0.3s

#8 [5/5] RUN echo "MY_VAR2 = $MY_VAR2"
#8 0.297 MY_VAR2 = my_value2
#8 DONE 0.3s
```

Reference

- [Dockerfile doesn't source .bashrc even in a single subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709653/dockerfile-doesnt-source-bashrc-even-in-a-single-subshell)

Comment: This is very much the Right Thing -- using a mechanism explicitly intended to allow configuration of noninteractive shells, vs trying to shim in a dotfile designed for use in initialization of interactive shells only. (For folks who want to follow this advice with `/bin/sh` rather than bash, change `BASH_ENV` to `ENV`)