# Dockerfile doesn't source .bashrc even in a single subshell

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I'm trying to source `.bashrc` but no luck

```
USER user
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo "export TEST_VAR=test" >> /home/user/.bashrc && tail /home/user/.bashrc && source /home/user/.bashrc && echo "1 \"${TEST_VAR} 2\" var" && exit 1
```

I expect that this `RUN` command print `1 "test" 2` but what i get is that

```
Step 13/40 : RUN echo "export TEST_VAR=test" >> /home/user/.bashrc && tail /home/user/.bashrc && source /home/user/.bashrc && echo "1 \"${TEST_VAR}\" 2" && exit 1
 ---> Running in b870d36e9dd0
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
export TEST_VAR=test
1 "" 2
```

What's wrong with handling shells in docker? I just wanted to source `~/.bashrc` once and use all exposed variables in subsequent command below `source` call but it doesn't even work in a single subshell joined with &&

Comment: @charlesduffy it's ok but i need to get bashrc's inner calls that modify `PATH` to be able to call binaries. It's kinda ok if i will have to `source` bashrc in each subsequent call of `RUN` but it doesn't work in a single expression and i don't know why

Comment: (1) `set -x` is your friend. (2) For noninteractive shells, use `BASH_ENV`, not `.bashrc`. You can use a Docker `ENV` to point `BASH_ENV` (or `ENV` if running with `sh` instead of `bash`) to a file you want sourced into noninteractive shells.

Comment: (What I mean by (1): `set -x` before the `source` command will show in logs what `source` is actually executing)

Comment: ...and consider `declare -p TEST_VAR` instead of `echo "${TEST_VAR}"` -- the former doesn't run the risk of early expansion removing the reference before the `source` command is run. (That's probably not a risk here, but easier to use constructs where one doesn't need to think about the possibility in the first place).

Comment: @charlesduffy i guess it is a problem with bashrc itself. `set -x` shows only `++ case $- in` and `++ return` and looks like it doesn't process the file further

Comment: @IC_ That's a common idiom. If `i` isn't in the value of `$-` (indicating a noninteractive shell), `.bashrc` returns early.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `~/.bashrc` contains something similar to:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

That is very normal - `.bashrc` is meant to be used in interactive sessions only. Because `RUN` is non-interactive, it just exits.

Aaaanyway, I would recommend, if you want to only add environment variables, output them to `/etc/profile.d` and `. /etc/profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Most paths in Docker don't read shell dotfiles at all.  You need to use other approaches to provide configuration to your application; for example, Dockerfile `ENV` to set environment variables or an entrypoint wrapper script if you need things to be set up dynamically before starting the container.

Let's look specifically at a reduced form of your example:

```sh
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo "export TEST_VAR=test" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "$TEST_VAR"
```

[Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the GNU Bash manual lists out which dotfiles are read in which case.  For the last line Docker combines the `SHELL` and `RUN` lines to run the equivalent of

```sh
/bin/bash -c 'echo "$TEST_VAR"'
```

but the `bash` instance is neither an interactive nor a login shell, so the only dotfile that's automatically read is one named in a `$BASH_ENV` environment variable.  ([POSIX `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) doesn't specify anything about any shell dotfiles at all.)

This further applies to the image's default `CMD`, which also will get run with `sh -c` (or the alternate `SHELL`) and it won't read dotfiles.  If the `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT` or `RUN`) uses JSON-array syntax, it won't invoke a shell at all, and again won't read dotfiles.

The only case where shell dotfiles will be read is if the main container command is an interactive shell, and this won't typically be the common case.

```sh
docker run --rm -it yourimage /bin/bash         # reads .bashrc
docker run --rm -it yourimage /bin/bash --login # also reads .profile, .bash_login
```

This means you should almost never try to edit the `.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, or any similar files.  If you need to set environment variables as in the example, use Dockerfile `ENV` instead.

```sh
ENV TEST_VAR=test
RUN echo "$TEST_VAR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from the question

```bash
FROM ubuntu

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV BASH_ENV="/etc/bash_env"
RUN echo "export TEST_VAR=test" >> $BASH_ENV

RUN echo $TEST_VAR
```

```bash
#6 [3/3] RUN echo $TEST_VAR
#6 0.239 test
#6 DONE 0.3s
```

**Reference**

- [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)
- [Dockerfile: $HOME is set, but becomes blank when using it to define other environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839369/dockerfile-home-is-set-but-becomes-blank-when-using-it-to-define-other-enviro/60848005#60848005)